# (Android) How to disable scrolling of certain elements of nested recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, vertical-scrolling, nestedrecyclerview

[With this link you can navigate to the image of my recyclerview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqgIH.jpg).
Here I have vertical recyclerview inside horizontal recyclerview. The horizontal scrolling works fine because I have used LinearSnapHelper. So everytime I scroll horizontally, one of the displays of date and hours is positioned in the center. The problem is that I want to disable the vertical scrolling of 2 recyclerviews of the image which are on the edges, so the only central recyclerview can be scrolled vertically at that moment.

Looking forward to suggestions!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: setNestedScrolling=false

Comment: @AslamHossin I've tried that, but it doesn't work, thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I would like to help you with your problem

Could you please submit code snippets of your main activity, main XML file, and the activity that this layout is put in?